# xcode 13 - trying to trigger a local Notification every 30 sec using a public function

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uilocalnotification

Im trying to trigger a local Notification every 30 sec but I'm getting an error "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'"
I just opened a new project on Xcode 13 where it says hello world and wanted to trigger a local Notification using the below A() functions after the "hello world" ContentView() function

what am i doing wrong? is there a better approach ?

thank you
+++++++++++++++++

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

@main
struct ozApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {    /// error /// Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'            
            ContentView()
            A()
        }
    }
}

public func A(){
    // Swift
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Title"
    content.body = "Body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                   
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 30, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    print("INSIDE NOTIFICATION")
    
   // let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: CommonViewController.Identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    //print("INSIDE NOTIFICATION")
                    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
        }
    })
    

}
```

Comment: Only views should be in the body `A` is not a `View`. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) they will get you started. `func` should be in a `Void` if included in a `body`

Comment: read the tutorial and the SwitUI basics, then replace your `A()` after `ContentView` with `.onAppear { A() }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@main
struct ozApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
              .onAppear { A() }
        }
    }
}
```

and the time interval must be at least 60 if repeating.